# Enum with other enum as type

Tags: java, generics, parameters, enums

I want to have an Enum like this:

```
public enum Type {
    STRING, INTEGER, BOOLEAN, LIST(Type);

    Type t;

    Type() { this.t = this; )
    Type(Type t) { this.t = t; }

}
```

Such that I can enter various `Type`s for `LIST`, like being able to call `Type.LIST(STRING)`. Is this possible in Java?

Comment: It's not possible to pass data to the constructor of an enum definition from outside that enum, but, please explain how you want to use it, and what you are trying to achieve and I/we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: @weston I want to create a Map<String, Type> to define Types for certain values. I don't want to use Object since I don't want to instantiate any objects, trying to keep it as abstract as possible, limited to only Strings, Numbers, Booleans, Lists containing any of the other enums.

Comment: You can; just have the constructor take a `Type...`, but I imagine you'll only be able to hold `Type`s that have already been defined above `LIST`.

Comment: @JacobG. Yeah but that has two issues. First being that I would only be able to call the `Type`s from within the enum and second that I will be able to only define `LIST(X)` once, so when I define `LIST(STRING)`, I won't be able to define `LIST(INTEGER)`.

Comment: So, would this work for you? `public enum Type {
    STRING, INTEGER, BOOLEAN, LIST_STRING, LIST_INTEGER, LIST_BOOLEAN` or do you need `LIST(LIST(X))`?

Comment: @weston Yeah I thought of that too, but as you say, I would also need `LIST(LIST(X))`

Comment: Well enums are limited, you can't have an unknown amount of entries. So you can't have `LIST(LIST(LIST(LIST(...)))` as a separate `Type` enum. You'll need a class, but that doesn't mean you have to instantiate lots of objects nessasarily.... you can use a flyweight pattern for instance, but it's a signifiant effort and might be premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum`s are limited, you can't have an unknown amount of entries. So you can't have LIST(LIST(LIST(LIST(...))) as a separate `Type` enum. You'll need a class, but that doesn't mean you have to instantiate lots of objects necessarily:

It may be premature optimization, but you can use a flyweight pattern to ensure that you can't get more than one instance of a `Type`:

```
package com.example;

public final class Type {

    public enum LeafType {
        STRING,
        INTEGER,
        BOOLEAN
    }

    //Gives you the familiar enum syntax
    public static final Type STRING = new Type(LeafType.STRING);
    public static final Type INTEGER = new Type(LeafType.INTEGER);
    public static final Type BOOLEAN = new Type(LeafType.BOOLEAN);

    private final LeafType leafType;

    private final Type listType;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    // This is the cache that prevents creation of multiple instances

    private Type listOfMeType;

    private Type(LeafType leafType) {
        if (leafType == null) throw new RuntimeException("X");
        this.leafType = leafType;
        listType = null;
    }

    private Type(Type type) {
        leafType = null;
        listType = type;
    }

    /**
     * Get the type that represents a list of this type
     */
    public Type list() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (listOfMeType == null) {
                listOfMeType = new Type(this);
            }
            return listOfMeType;
        }
    }

    public boolean isList() {
        return listType != null;
    }

    /**
     * If this type is a list, will return what type of list it is
     */
    public Type getListType() {
        if (!isList()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a list");
        }
        return listType;
    }

    /**
     * If this type is a leaf, will return what type of leaf it is
     */
    public LeafType getLeafType() {
        if (isList()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a leaf");
        }
        return leafType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (isList()) {
            return "LIST(" + getListType() + ")";
        }
        return getLeafType().toString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

Simple type:

```
Type string = Type.STRING;
```

List:

```
Type stringList = Type.STRING.list();
```

List of list:

```
Type stringListList = Type.STRING.list().list();
```

And you can never get in the situation where you have two instances of `Type` that describe the same type, e.g.:

```
Type t1 = Type.BOOLEAN.list().list().list();
Type t2 = Type.BOOLEAN.list().list().list();

System.out.println(t1 == t2 ? "Same instance" : "Not same instance");
```

I added `toString` for debugging:

```
Type listListListInt = Type.INTEGER.list().list().list();
System.out.println(listListListInt);
```

Gives:

```
LIST(LIST(LIST(INTEGER)))
```

Comment: I've fixed some initial bugs I spotted while making the `toString`.